# Update dictionary entries without specifying them all

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a way to update or append to all the entries in a dictionary that avoid writing out all of the entries. For example consider:

```
records = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}

for i in range(0, 10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        records['a'].append(i)
        records['b'].append(i**2)
        records['c'].append(i**4)
    else:
        records['a'].append(i)
        records['b'].append(i**3)
        records['c'].append(i**5)
```

This isn't too hard to read, but if the `records` dict has more entries or the loop has more conditions this can quickly increase in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't keep referencing 3 separate lists inside a dictionary. If you are adding to all three targets in all branches of your code, you can just collect tuples in a single list. You can always transpose those back into separate lists:

```
entries = []

for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        entries.append((i, i ** 2, i ** 4))
    else:
        entries.append((i, i ** 3, i ** 5))

records = dict(zip('abc', zip(*entries)))
```

That loop can then also be turned into a list comprehension, if so desired.

Another option is to use local variables to reference those lists; you have 3 fixed targets that are mutable here, so creating a fixed number of locals is trivial and already saves you a large amount of boilerplate:

```
a, b, c = records['a'], records['b'], records['c']
# use a, b and c inside your loops
```

Yet another option is to dispatch to separate functions for each target:

```
def a_from_i(i):
    return i

def b_from_i(records, i):
    return i ** 2 if i % 2 == 0 else i ** 3

def c_from_i(records, i):
    return i ** 4 if i % 2 == 0 else i ** 5

records = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
dispatchers = {'a': a_from_i, 'b': b_from_i, 'c': c_from_i}

for i in range(10):
    for key, handler in dispatchers.items():
        records[key].append(handler(i))
```

This is probably overkill *here*, but as the complexity of your problem grows, using separate functions for each dictionary entry would let you focus on each type of datapoint you are building in separate units of code that can be tested on their own.

Rather than a hard-coded dictionary like I used above, you could have decorator add to the dispatcher registryers if you need to extend and add handlers easily later on. While using dispatch patterns can be a bit slower (function calls have overhead, re-testing `i` in each function repeats the test, etc.) the benefits for maintainability are great!

Comment: this seems unnecessary

Comment: @Hippolippo: how so? It depends heavily on the exact nature of the loops. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Very clever solution! +1

Comment: @MartijnPieters so the question is asking how you would add a value to many elements in a dict, right?

Comment: @Hippolippo The question is asking how to update many entries, in a dict, from many different conditions. This is a slim example, but the actual problem has >10 conditions with >15 entries. That would add >150 lines, whereas this solution adds 10-20 lines.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the keys() method:

```
records = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
keys = sorted(list(records.keys()))

for i in range(0, 10):
    for index, k in enumerate(keys):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            records[k].append(pow(i, index*2 if index else 1))
        else:
            records[k].append(pow(i, 1 + index*2))

print(records)
```

Or even start with a simple list of your keys, which can lead to something like:

```
keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
records = {k: [(pow(i, ((i % 2) + index*2) if index else 1)) for i in range(0, 10)] for index, k in enumerate(keys)}
```

Comment: i would be happy to know why it was downvoted, maybe I misunderstand something?

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through a dictionary in python using a dictionary's `.keys` and `.items` methods for keys and key,value tuples respectively. You can build a solution around it.

```
records = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
records_keys = sorted(records.keys()) #Because dictionaries inherently have no order, it is important to reference them reliably during iteration if the condition depends on it
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        for power, key in enumerate(records_keys):
            records[key].append(i ** max(1, 2*power))
    else:
        for power, key in enumerate(records_keys):
            records[key].append(i ** max(1, 2*power + 1))
```

In the example you provided, you can also reduce the condition further, Using something along these lines. However, i do not know if you can apply it to your real problem.

```
records = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
records_keys = sorted(records.keys())
for i in range(10):
    for power, key in enumerate(records_keys):
        records[key].append(i ** max(1, 2*power + i%2))
```